# VBA or VBScript - How do I move a window (in this instance OSK.EXE) to a specific set of co-ordinates?

Tags: vba, vbscript, keyboard, move, on-screen-keyboard

Basically, I have a degree of automation that requires the Onscreen Keyboard app within windows to run.

- When it runs, I would ideally need it to open within the same set of co-ordinates for any machine that it is run from.

Even more ideal, would be a way to make sure that if there is a difference in resolution, that the co-ordinates of the keys will not change. - This may be a step too far??

Any support is appreciated!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is VB6 (same language as VBA). You can get it compiled in https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=e2f0ce17a268a4fa&id=E2F0CE17A268A4FA%21121 (Topmost.zip).

It reads the VB6 command line so needs to be changed for use in Office.

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Public Const SWP_DRAWFRAME = &H20
Public Const SWP_FRAMECHANGED = &H20        '  The frame changed: send WM_NCCALCSIZE
Public Const SWP_HIDEWINDOW = &H80
Public Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
Public Const SWP_NOCOPYBITS = &H100
Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Public Const SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = &H200      '  Don't do owner Z ordering
Public Const SWP_NOREDRAW = &H8
Public Const SWP_NOREPOSITION = &H200
Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Public Const SWP_NOZORDER = &H4
Public Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40

Public Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long

Sub Main()
On Error Resume Next
HWND_TOPMOST = -1

CmdLine = Command()

A = Split(CmdLine, Chr(32), 2, 1)
B = Split(A(0), "x", 2, 1)

hwindows = FindWindow(vbNullString, A(1))
Ret = SetWindowPos(hwindows, HWND_NOTOPMOST, B(0), B(1), 0, 0, SWP_NOREPOSITION + SWP_NOSIZE)
If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox "Set Pos Error is " & Err.LastDllError
End Sub
```

Comment: How many times do I have to tell you this - they are. They are not similar - they are the same. IT IS VBA that is hosted by either Office or a VB6 app object. Use OBJECT BROWSER to see. Also the language documentation (ie instr, msgbox etc) for VB6 is called VBA. Only the hosting object is called VB6.